# UITableView Selection Addition Problem

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, ios

Having this problem that needs to be adressed unfortunately....

I am adding a custom UIButton to my UITableView Cell when it is selected however as I scroll down into the TableView I find that multiple cells are getting the buttons attached:

Here is my code:

http://pastie.org/1309795

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

You're being bitten by cell reuse. You need to learn how to sanitize your cells when you get a cell that has been recycled.

Comment: How can I go about fixing that?

Comment: The tableview documentation and sample code in the tableviewsuite should help you out with this. There's no need for me to reproduce it here.

Comment: This portion of Apple's Table View Programming Guide discusses cell reuse: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW10